# Partially matching strings in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was doing some research today, and I faced a problem. I needed to do a "count" on all a column of strings, but only if they match a certain string. Even if it's partially.

Example

```
List of Movie Titles

---------------  
- Inception       
- Mulan       
- Inception     
- Inception
- The Dark Knight
- The Dark Knight
- The White Knight
- Some Knight
```

Assuming I want to know how many times titles that contains "Knight" has appeared, how do I count it?

I've added my own answer below.

Comment: Has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do so:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*" & "Knight" & "*")
```

Set a countif, and state the column. That's the known bit.

The way to state the criteria is to first say `"*"`, which would match any characters, which is concatenated with a `"Knight"`, and then finally concatenated again with a `"*"`.

This would match anything that has the partial string `"Knight"` in it.

Comment: yeah i know. :) glad it helped you. There's no question. I'm merely sharing information.